# How to truncate the first digit of a number?

Tags: sed, grep

For example, my file has the following data:

```
$ cat sample.txt 

19999119999,string1,dddddd
18888135790,string2,dddddd
15555555500,string3,dddddd
```

This is a sample data. How can we remove ONLY first digit from each row? My output should be:

```
$ cat output.txt
9999119999,string1,dddddd
8888135790,string2,dddddd
5555555500,string3,dddddd
```

Is there any way to parse each line character wise using grep or sed?
Or any other way to get the desired output?

Comment: Here's a simple sed string: sed 's/^[0-9]//'

Comment: So it is a matter of deleting the first char in the line, right?

Comment: What should happen if the number in the first field is a single-digit number? Should that digit still be deleted, leaving no number? If not (so you only want to truncate the first digit of a multi-digit number), then you need to be a bit more complex than `sed 's/^[0-9]//'` — you need `sed 's/^[0-9]\([0-9]\)/\1/'` instead (look for two digits at the start of line and replace just the 2nd). If you're confident you'll never have a single-digit number in the first field, you can use the original simpler script — using regular expressions is often a balancing act between robustness and simplicity.

Answer (score 4):

You just need to print from the second character on:

```
$ cut -c2- file
9999119999,string1,dddddd
8888135790,string2,dddddd
5555555500,string3,dddddd
```

Or, using `sed`, remove the first char:

```
$ sed 's/^.//' file
9999119999,string1,dddddd
8888135790,string2,dddddd
5555555500,string3,dddddd
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$ sed -r 's/^[0-9](.*)/\1/' sample.txt
```

**Output:**

```
9999119999,string1,dddddd
8888135790,string2,dddddd
5555555500,string3,dddddd
```

- **^[0-9]** - The first digit of each line
- **(.*)** - The content of each line except the first digit
- **\1** - Denote the content of **(.*)**

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: does it remove all occurances of 1 from the data? And can you please explain your script?

Comment: Simpler: `sed 's/^[0-9]//' sample.txt`. Or, if the first digit is always `1` as intruder seems to be saying:  `sed 's/^1//' sample.txt`

Comment: @intruder - I have updated my answer, sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

Grep can solve this with a look behind. For that you need `-P` option :

```
grep -Po '(?<=^\d)(.+)' file
```

or in shorthand :

```
grep -Po '^\d\K.+' file
```

The `(?<=^\d)`/`^\d\K` part is the look behind that matches the first digit.